# How to use sed to examine the line without specific content?

Tags: sed

I made a toy file named toy, its content is like:

```
aaa
bbb
```

My first idea is to use:

```
$ sed -n '/[^a]/ p' toy
bbb
```

it prints out bbb, but when I added **'bb ab'**
to the end of toy file. I found it lose its power

```
$ sed -n '/[^a]/ p' toy
bbb
bb ab
```

How should I scan the whole line with the pattern?

Comment: Do you essentially want to mimic `grep -v`?

Comment: @cbuckley, nope, didn't dig into grep yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if I understand the question correctly... What exactly is it you want to achieve?

Anyway, the regex you use will print out any line that contains a character that is not an "a". So lines that consist of "a" chars *only* will be skipped.

If you want to filter out lines that do contain an a you have to do it differently:

```
sed '/a/d' toy
```

This will delete any line that contains an "a", all others will be printed.

Comment: I want to rule out a line containing 'a', no matter how many, in what place

Comment: I got the idea now, I can use " a\+ " to specify 1 or more a here. Thank you, buddy.

Comment: Not necessary to use the + quantifier here.

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of the following to print non-matching lines:

```
sed -n '/pattern/!p' toy
sed '/pattern/d' toy
```

From [Handy one-liners for sed](http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/doc/sed.html).

Comment: Looks nice, but I don't know how to use it, I tried it with my understood, and didn't figure out a workable plan. This is raise another problem to replace the current problem. You know how to use it to deal with this question?

Comment: uh... posted a dup. answer... removed. +1 yours

Comment: I got a feeling that I'll been down voted. But please try yourself what did you got by use " sed -n '/[^a]/ d' toy " to toy file.

Comment: @Zen because `/[^a]/` means "match a line that contains any character that's not an a", and `bb ab` matches that. It sounds like you want "match a line that doesn't contain an a", which is different.

Comment: @Zen: If you use -n and the d (delete) modifier together you will not get anything printed. -n says "don't print except when I tell you to" (using  "p").

Comment: @some-non-descript-user, thank you, I was blinded by anger. Now alright. Thank you again.

Comment: @cbuckley, nice website, by the way